# classcastexception in Android

Tags: android

I'am new to Android. I just created a simple app with a button and 'onClickListener'. But using these two lines:

```
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the `onCreate()` method causes `ClassCastException`. But without these two lines, the app is working fine. what would the problem?

Comment: put your full code n xml

Comment: what type of button did you use in the xml layout?

Comment: r u sure .. u r using button..if it is pls check the initialisation in activity..  private Button button; button = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button01);

Answer (score 0):

//if you are using ImageButton or ImageView in your xml and you are declaring code like below you will the exception as `ClassCastException`.

```
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

//for that you need to change your ImageView or ImageButton to Button to declare corresponding widget in code